Understanding お前一人じゃ雑魚に一発撃って終わりだろ
In Konosuba chapter 4, Megumin was about to face the demon lord general by herself, then she got warned:

お前一人じゃ雑魚に一発撃って終わりだろっ

It seems like the term 雑魚 indirectly refers to Megumin, right? The demon lord general previously called everyone using 雑魚 in the story. I could be wrong because when I checked some fan translation and it says "with you alone, I'm sure it will be the end once you shoot your single explosion at the small fry."


雑魚 does NOT mean Megumin here, it means some weakling monsters like dictionary says. Fan translation seems reasonable in this aspect.
Megumin is known to be able to shoot explosion magic only once a day, and it is expected she would meet enemies including weaklings during journey to the castle... so, speaker expected that Megumin has to shoot her once-a-day magic to these weaklings and that will be the end of her.

Thanks, I almost forgot about that fact..
